# Create RSS feed from Google Drive?

Tags: rss, google-drive-api

I've been searching but it appears that while there is an ability to create an RSS feed for photos from PicasaWeb/Google+ there does not appear to be a similar ability for photos that exist on Google Drive.  I've also found that Flickr allows this feature but I'd rather not have to move all my photos around.  Does anyone know if it's possible to create a public RSS feed for photos on Google Drive?

Comment: I wouldn't bet on Google adding RSS feeds anywhere, their recent track record is toward less open protocols... including RSS.